# How can I set the number of initial empty (orderable) items in an InlinePanel?

Tags: wagtail

I have an `Orderable` model called `SetListItem` with a `ParentalKey` on a `ClusterableModel` called `FloorWithSets`. The parent `FloorWithSets` model defines using an `InlinePanel` to control adding/ordering/removing of the `SetListItem`s. The issue I have is that the admin form automatically renders three empty `SetListItem`s for each `FloorWithSets`, and I cannot find any way to control this setting.

The `InlinePanel` class takes [parameters](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels-and-model-clusters) to, e.g. set the minimum and maximum number of items, but nothing to set the number of initial empty items rendered.

I cannot find any information about this in the Wagtail docs. I've also dug into the [source](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f7ff6d39c45fc55c3a77cc5e48c4e4fbfa1c2f5f/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py) for `InlinePanel` and `EditHandler` but cannot find anything I could override.

I do see from the [InlinePanel template file](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f7ff6d39c45fc55c3a77cc5e48c4e4fbfa1c2f5f/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers/inline_panel.html) that there is a hidden input with id ending `-INITIAL_FORMS` which is being rendered via `self.formset.management_form`. The value of this field is consistently lower than a neighbouring hidden input with id ending `-TOTAL_FORMS`, which makes sense. I just don't understand where the value is coming from or how to control it.

The only information I can find about this `INITIAL_FORMS` all seems to relate to testing, (e.g. [this documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/advanced_topics/testing.html#wagtail.tests.utils.form_data.inline_formset)) and I cannot see how to relate what that says to what I need.

```py
class FloorWithSets(ClusterableModel):
    page = ParentalKey(EventPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='floor_with_sets')

    FLOOR_CHOICES = [
        ('1', 'X'),
        ('2', 'Y'),
        ('3', 'Z'),
    ]
    floor = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=FLOOR_CHOICES,
        default='1',
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('floor'),
        InlinePanel('set_list', label=_("set")),
    ]


class SetListItem(Orderable):
    floor = ParentalKey(FloorWithSets, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='set_list')

    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name=_('artist'))
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name=_('label'))
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('start time'))
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('end time'))

    set_list_item = FieldRowPanel([
        FieldPanel('artist', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('label', classname="col6")
    ])

    set_list_item_details = FieldRowPanel([
        FieldPanel('start_time', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('end_time', classname="col6")
    ])

    panels = [set_list_item, set_list_item_details]
```

Comment: Please post your `models.py`

Comment: I have nearly the same setup and am having no problems.  The only difference is that my `InlinePanel` is inside a `MultiFieldPanel`.  You could try `InlinePanel('set_list', min_num=0, label=_("set")),` just to see what that does.  You could also try `class SetListItem(ClusterableModel, Orderable):`.  I'm wondering if you have three revisions of `EventPage` and this is somehow causing the problem.  Just offering a few guesses here.

Comment: The three extra forms is a Django default (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory), but it gets overridden on Wagtail's forms (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f7ff6d39c45fc55c3a77cc5e48c4e4fbfa1c2f5f/wagtail/admin/forms/models.py#L58-L60) so not sure why that wouldn't be taking effect. Hopefully that gives you somewhere to look, at least...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'm still digging, but I think we need to redefine how we've modeled a couple of things. Will update when I have something concrete.

Comment: I think I've just run into this same problem. Are you using nested `InlinePanel`s? I only started seeing this when I nested `InlinePanel`s. I've got a `class HomePage(Page)` which uses an `InlinePanel` to add `class Feature(ClusterableModel, Orderable)`. The `Feature` uses an `InlinePanel` to render forms for `class FeatureCallToAction(Orderable)`. Inside the `InlinePanel` for a new `Feature`, I get three forms for `FeatureCallToAction`.

Comment: I think I've figured out why this is happening, but I don't have a fix yet. Because `FloorWithSets` inherits from `ClusterableModel`, the form it gets is not a `WagtailAdminModelForm`, but a `ClusterForm` from django-modelcluster. The metaclass for `ClusterForm` (`ClusterFormMetaClass`) has a field `extra_form_count` set to 3, which gets passed to `childformset_factory` here https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/blob/master/modelcluster/forms.py#L275. So if there's a way to override that field, that should remove the extra inline panels. Haven't figured that last bit out yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found a solution. Try creating a custom `Form` class for your `EventPage` model with a custom metaclass like so:

```py
class EventPageFormMetaclass(WagtailAdminModelFormMetaclass):
    @classmethod
    def child_form(cls):
        return EventPageForm


class EventPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm, metaclass=EventPageFormMetaclass):
    pass


class EventPage(Page):
    # Whatever you have in your model

    base_form_class = EventPageForm
```

I believe the problem stems from the fact that the `ClusterFormMetaclass` is [hard-coded](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/blob/master/modelcluster/forms.py#L217-L219) to create instances of `ClusterForm` for child models. So your `EventPage` gets a `WagtailAdminPageForm`, but the `FloorWithSets` models gets a `ClusterForm`. If you stop there, it's fine, but when `FloorWithSets` generates *it's* inline panels, it does so as a `ClusterForm`, whose metaclass has `extra_form_count` set to 3, as opposed to the `WagtailAdminPageForm` whose metaclass has it set to 0.

So the solution above creates a new `Form` class, whose metaclass overrides the `child_form` class method to return a `Form` class with `extra_form_count` set to 0.

Whew.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'd gotten as far as working out that it was the nested InlinePanels, but that's all.